# Plaid API php cURL not sending post data

Tags: php, api, curl, plaid

I am trying to translate the below cURL to php cURL:

$ curl -X POST https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token \

> -d client_id="$plaid_client_id" \
>     -d secret="$plaid_secret" \
>     -d public_token="$public_token_from_plaid_link_module"

using this code:

```
    $data = array(
        "cliend_id"=>"test_id",
        "secret"=>"test_secret",
        "public_token"=>"test,fidelity,connected");
    $string = http_build_query($data);

    echo $string;

    //initialize session
    $ch=curl_init("https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token");

    //set options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //execute session
    $exchangeToken = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $exchangeToken;
    //close session
    curl_close($ch);
```

and I am getting this response:

cliend_id=test_id&secret=test_secret&public_token=test%2Cfidelity%2Cconnected{ "code": 1100, "message": "client_id missing", "resolve": "Include your Client ID so we know who you are." }

I am not sure what is wrong with my format that is keeping plaid from recognizing the client_id portion of the post.  For further reference, I have more detail below.

The below is taken from the plaid site that can be found by searching "plaid api quickstart":

---

Reference
/exchange_token Endpoint

The /exchange_token endpoint is available in both the tartan and production environments.
Method  Endpoint    Required Parameters     Optional Parameters
POST    /exchange_token     client_id, secret, public_token     account_id

The /exchange_token endpoint has already been integrated into the plaid-node, plaid-go, plaid-ruby, and plaid-python client libraries. Support for plaid-java is coming soon.

If you are working with a library that does not yet support the /exchange_token endpoint you can simply make a standard HTTP request:

$ curl -X POST https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token \

> -d client_id="$plaid_client_id" \
>     -d secret="$plaid_secret" \
>     -d public_token="$public_token_from_plaid_link_module"

For a valid request, the API will return a JSON response similar to:

{
  "access_token": "foobar_plaid_access_token"
}

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are sending `cliend_id` but the server expects `client_id`:

```
$data = array(
    "client_id"=>"test_id", // Use client_id instead of cliend_id
    "secret"=>"test_secret",
    "public_token"=>"test,fidelity,connected");
```

Comment: Many hours of my life gone because of that letter.  Thank you, and sorry to waste your time...